# how to calculate time left using string minus another string?

Tags: php, time, timer

i have lets say a `$value = 5;` and the valnue means 5 minutes, and i have a file saved on the server and getting modified a lot called `check.txt` i want a code to do a calculation of if timenow - timemodification of file <= 0 in H:i:s from the main $value of 5 minutes then continue, else echo please wait minutes left from the time now - filetimemodification of the main value of 5 minutes = $timeleft in m:s format.

i'm testing on the current code but i keep getting a value of -1376352747

my code which is know is bad :) is

```
$filename = 'check.txt';
$time = date("H:i:s");
$time = str_replace("00", "24", $time);
$filemodtime = filemtime($filename);
$timeleft = $time - $filemodtime;
$h = explode(':', $time);
$h = $h[0];
$h = str_replace("00", "24", $h);
$m = explode(':', $time);
$m = $m[1];
$s = explode(':', $time);
$s = $s[2];
$hms = ("$h:$m:$s");

if (count($filemodtime - $time) <= 0) {

echo "you can continue";
}

else {

echo " please wait $timeleft";
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filemtime()` function returns a UNIX-timestamp in seconds, and the `time()` function returns the current time as a UNIX-timestamp. So by using that difference, you get the file's age in seconds.

```
$age = time() - filemtime($filename);

// if older then 5 minutes (5 * 60 secounds)
if($age > $value*60)
{
    // good
}
else
{
   $time_left = $value * 60 - $age;
   $time_left_secounds = $time_left % 60;
   $time_left_minutes = ($time_left - $time_left_secounds) / 60;
   $formated_time_left = sprintf("%02d:%02d", $time_left_minutes, $time_left_secounds);

   echo "Please wait {$formated_time_left}";
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot :)
but can you help me make it as a countdown from 5 ? it now acting as normal counter, i want a count down from $value
thanks again

Comment: and its showing time in seconds if time is less than 5 minutes, i will need it in minutes:seconds format if possible
thanks again

Comment: This `$time_left = $value * 60 - $age:` should read as `$time_left = $value * 60 - $age;` otherwise, it will cause a parse error. Colon should be a semi-colon at the end of `$age`

Comment: thanks a lot, sorry i cannot vote up due to low reputation :)

Comment: @Fred, thanks a lot, i noticed that when i got the error, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to work with time() rather than date().
that way, you can substract the file time from the current time() function, and see if it is bigger than 5 minutes * 60 seconds.

Good luck!

Comment: forgot: time is a function which returns the amount of seconds passed since 1.1.1970 12:00:00